# media queries simpler usage?

Tags: css, media-queries

Perhaps this is stupid to ask, but is there anyway to do something like this:

```
html{
  @include responsive("font-size", 11px,
    (
       600px: 100%,
       800px: 120%,
      1180px: 130%,
      1300px: 140%,
      1750px: 160%,
      1900px: 180%,
      2100px: 200%,
      2400px: 19px
    )
  );
}
```

this is taking from some bugsnag platform(I don't rly know what it is), but that's not important. I want to know if i can do something like this with pure css? For smooth responsive changes when re-sizing window/to any resolution changes.

And also, how should I use the fallback with such thing for older browsers?

Thanks!

Comment: do you need to obtain those exact values at those given breakpoints?

Comment: No, I want to know how to make this simple "resolution: value" table for some specific style(like font-size in the example). Sorry for my bad English

Comment: What isn't explicit in this file is if each value is below breakpoint or above? Is it Mobile First or not? For N breakpoints you need (N+1) values or else need to know if it's dektop first or mobile first...

Comment: By 'pure CSS', do you mean without JavaScript and/or without any preprocessor (Sass, LESS, PostCSS)? A mixin would do the job. sass-list manages such lists but from its author itself, it's rarely desirable to have a project complicated to the point you *need* lists. KISS ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer:**
[No.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

**Long(-er) answer:**
The only place in CSS that a series of comma-separated media queries may be specified is as [optional parameters to the @import At-Rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import), and these don't have their own styles or shorthand.

Additionally, your proposed syntax is misleading. What does a "600px" media query mean? [Media queries are either set states (e.g. "screen") or key-value pairs (e.g. "max-width: 600px").](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) As such, this would wind up looking more like "max-width: 2400px: 19px", which is confusing and syntactically inappropriate in almost any language.

Comment: So I should use rules each time, correct? Like `@media (max-width:600px) { 100% }` and `@media (max-width:800px) { 120% }` and so on. Is this is the only css-way to do this(simpler)?

Comment: Correct. But don't forget; the media query contains all of the information (including the target and the attribute), so it would actually look more like this: `@media (max-width:600px) { html { width: 100% } }`.

Comment: Thank you, ConnorCMcKee!